# How can you chain group by using EF core 3

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I want to generate a query using EF core 3.1 equivalent to this one:

```sql
SELECT g.Date, Count(*) countIntervals
FROM(
        SELECT
            TODATETIMEOFFSET(DATETIME2FROMPARTS(DATEPART(year, myTimestamp),1,1,0,0,0,0,0), '+00:00') Date,
            DATEPART(month, myTimestamp) - (DATEPART(month, myTimestamp) % 3) interval
        GROUP BY 
            DATEPART(year, myTimestamp),
            DATEPART(month, myTimestamp) - (DATEPART(month, myTimestamp) % 3), 
            UserId
    ) as g
GROUP BY Date
```

here is my use case: "i want to count all intervals in each year"

I tried this in C# but i get an error `System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression could not be translated.`:

```cs
var query = _context.DatesTable
    .GroupBy(m => new
    {
        Year = m.Timestamp.Year,
        interval = m.Timestamp.Month - m.Timestamp.Month % 3,
        UserId = m.UserId
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Date = new DateTimeOffset(g.Key.Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero),
        interval = g.Key.interval
    })
    .GroupBy(x => new { 
        Date = x.Date 
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Date = g.Key.Date ,
        CountIntervals = g.Count()
    });
    
    query.ToList()
```

I already tried to load data in memory using `AsEnumerable()`. That works but it's not efficient:

```cs
var query = _context.DatesTable
    .GroupBy(m => new
    {
        Year = m.Timestamp.Year,
        interval = m.Timestamp.Month - m.Timestamp.Month % 3,
        UserId = m.UserId
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Date = new DateTimeOffset(g.Key.Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero),
        interval = g.Key.interval
    }).AsEnumerable();

    var result = query.GroupBy(x => new { 
        Date = x.Date 
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Date  = g.Key.Date,
        CountIntervals = g.Count()
    });
    
    query.ToList()
```

Is there any efficient solution for this query ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```cs
var query = _context.DatesTable
    .GroupBy(m => new
    {
        Year = m.Timestamp.Year,
        interval = m.Timestamp.Month - m.Timestamp.Month % 3,
        UserId = m.UserId
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Year = g.Key.Year,
        interval = g.Key.interval
    })
    .GroupBy(x => new { 
        Year = x.Year 
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Year = g.Key.Year,
        CountIntervals = g.Count()
    });
    
var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I edited my question because it wasn't reflecting my issue. please update your answer accordinly

Answer (score 0):

A pretty direct transalation of your query goes like this.

```cs
var query = _context.DatesTable
    .GroupBy(m => new
    {
        Year = m.Timestamp.Year,
        interval = m.Timestamp.Month - m.Timestamp.Month % 3,
        UserId = m.UserId
    })
    .GroupBy(x => g.Key.Year)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Year = g.Key,
        CountIntervals = g.Count()
    });
    
var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I edited my question because it wasn't reflecting my issue. please update your answer accordinly

Comment: Not sure how well EF supports `DATETIMEOFFSET` and associated functions, but it's unclear why you are using it anyway. Why not just `Date = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)` alternatively just group by `Year = g.Key.Year,` as shown

Comment: I tried this `Date = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)` but looks like Ef core 3 doesn't support DateTime either. I ended up grouping with each datepart (in this query: `Year = g.Key.Year`) and doing the select after query evaluation.